# How to create a template types in Magic Draw?

Tags: c#, magic-draw

I have this signature[c#]:

```
public interface IUniJobber<T> : IJob where T : IMinimalJobContext;
```

How to create this template type in Magic Draw?

(Without code engineering sets :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. got to Specification of yout Type (e.g. DoubleClick on Class in the Containment-View)

   2. change the Properties to "All" or "Expert"
   3. in the TreeView of Specification you can see the entry "Template PArameter"
   4. "create" a new Template Parameter
   5. i think, in the first time you must choose any constraint Type